# How can we solve this matricial system?

Tags: matrices

The exercise:

Solve the system of matricial equations
$MAX+NY=M$

$NAX+PY=N$

I am trying to​ determine $X$ and $Y$, but I know I can't use something like $M^{-1}$ or $N^{-1}$ because I don't know if the matrices are invertible. I think I have to somehow isolate one variable in one equation and substitute it on the other, but I was not able to find any content explaining exercises like this one.

Comment: Is there any relationship between $M$ and $A$?

Comment: The exercise says nothing about a relation between $M$ and $A$. Where I found the question, the answear is illegible. Do you know what should I search to find any content about this exercise?

Comment: Honestly I've never seen a linear algebra exercise like this. It's really just a system of $2n^2$ ordinary real linear equations, but I don't see a quick way to solve it unless M and N are invertible. Perhaps thinking about the system as being of the form $TV=W$ where T is a $2n^2 \times 2n^2$ matrix and the other two are vectors in $2n^2$ dimensions will be fruitful, although tedious.